# Python question about exponents and int

Tags: python, floating-point

Out of curiosity I ran the following:

```
>>> int(1e100)
```

And, the output was:

```
10000000000000000159028911097599180468360808563945281389781327557747838772170381060813469985856815104L
```

Why? Why does this not look like:

```
10000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000L
```

Is this a product of the `int` function, or of the storage of a large `long`?

Comment: Try this instead: `10**100` you will get what you expect. There is no floating point involved in this method.

Comment: @keith - thanks. I don't have a practical need for this. I only tried out of curiosity.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`1e100` is a floating point number, with 53 bits of precision in the [significand](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Significand). The integer you're trying to represent requires 333 bits for exactness, so there is some rounding involved. The bottom bits are substituted to make the closest base 2 number to your desired result.

See: http://docs.python.org/tutorial/floatingpoint.html#representation-error

Answer (score 1):

It got converted to a float and then displayed as an integer. So welcome to the imprecise world of rounding

Answer (score 0):

1e100 is a float (in general, using the `e` implies float):

```
>>> type (1e100)
<type 'float'>
```